# Pick from array which is equal to some number

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of amounts something like this:

```
[ 100, 20, 80, 50, 150, 20, 10 .. ]
```

I have to pick from this array which is equal to some amount, say 200.

So, the amounts will be 150, 50 picked from the array.

I can build an algorithm which can iterate through the array again and again and check if amount is equal or not, but I want to know if is there an easy way?

Or I have to write an algo matching in loop and picking and checking?

Thanks.

**Example explanation:**

I have an array. **Say -> 100, 200, 300**

I have a another array. **Say -> 50,50,20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30**

I want to match by picking up a number from the first array(i.e 100) and matching by sum of numbers from the second array if it matches, else fine, I will skip it and try it for the next number (i.e. 200) in the array.

**EDIT:  Some clarification**

The array does not contain the exact matches. I matched it previously and removed from the array. So it only contains numbers that can be exactly the same.

It is fine if any sum is not matched by the given amount. I will simply skip if sum from array doesn't match.

Comment: Are you sure you can always hit the sum exactly?

Comment: It is nonsense to pick the number A if it is equal to the number A when you just have that number A. Do you want to _remove it_ from the list instead?

Comment: This looks like the [change making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) or the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: What you just described IS the easy way. I mean... there are lots of ways with a much, much better runtime, but you described the brute force approach, which is always the easiest to come up with and implement, because it involves very little thinking :D

Comment: you provide us with an incomplete, vague description of 'what should be', show no code, and you expect us to solve it?

Comment: @MatthewWatson, in change making problem result would be `150 50` not the one he wrote, so I'm not sure

Comment: @MatthewWatson so he instead wants to pick the sum... All right, his explanation was not really good imho

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde in change making prob you also want to sum

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak Yes, you are true. It should be 150, 50. Editing question

Comment: This seems a little bit like the [Coin sums problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=31) to me, you just want to check the combinations from the Array?

Comment: But change making problem allows repetitions. In this case Its not.

Comment: @Stultuske I have built something similar for Map<String,Float> values. But, I think it can be done a little easier way (in terms of performance).

Comment: Ok, to be more specific, this is the [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) which is a special case of the Knapsack problem, and (like the Knapsack problem) is NP-Complete.

Comment: To all, adding more description, give me a minute

Comment: Done, Added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you try to solve is called [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and belongs to [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problems.

> Given a set of integers and an integer s, does any non-empty subset
>   sum to s (...)

**No polynomial-time algorithm** to solve this problem **is known** (at the moment ;)).
You can check all subsets of your set which is `O(2^n)` if your set contains `n` elements.
Eventually if your set would be an infinite set, you could try solving the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem).

---

Still it can be solved (exponential complexity as I wrote above). Consider a function:

```
bool foundSum(set[], n, sum);
```

which returns *true* if the sum can be found, *false* otherwise. A simple recursive algorithm:

`foundSum(set,n,sum) = foundSum(set,n-1,sum) or foundSum(arr,n-1,sum-set[n-1])`

How it works? In each step you **check if the sum can be obtained if you in/exclude last element**.

Example implementation in C++ (can be easily written in Java):

```
bool foundSum(vector<int> set, int n, int sum) {
    if(sum == 0) return true;
    if(n == 0 and sum != 0) return false;

    int last = set[n-1];

    if(last > sum) return foundSum(set, n-1, sum);
    return foundSum(set,n-1,sum) or foundSum(set,n-1,sum-last);
}
```

Modified to print subset when answer is found: http://ideone.com/YysY2n

Comment: I am really not big fan of recursive function calls.. And I am unable to understand the most part of it. I was checking the output and it seems fine to me currently: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaGRZbGJrVUxZakk . How can I include numbers that are causing this to return true? I just get if possible to find a sum or not. If possible can you explain or point me where I can understand this type of recursive functions?

Comment: Every recursive algorithm can be written as an iterative one, but usually recursive ones are easier to implement (like in this case). How to understand it? I'd suggest a pencil and scrap of paper.

Comment: And take a look (prints subsets as u requested): http://ideone.com/YysY2n

Comment: Pencil and paper are always the best thing! Your ideone code runs fine on that site but prints nothing on tutorialspoint !

Comment: @kirtan403, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMc28yY1NwMXZsUkE hm?

Comment: This has the same code, but doesn't work! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbmhYT3l2TFczaDA  OMG :/

Comment: Add `return false;` at the end of a `foundSum()` function.

Comment: @kirtan403, you're welcome. Mark this post as an answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Sure. I checked and everything works fine. I am trying to debugging this, but unable to get this. Can you please explain what it does in recursion? Like what ifs are doing and what are you setting apart for recursion? I logged every message and debugging with break-points but unable to get the whole picture.

Comment: Use your scrap of paper and try to draw a tree of recursion, write the actual state of variables in each set (try it for a small set first) :)

Comment: I did it, but unable to find the pattern

Comment: I got it finally. After creating so many graphs, I finally understood. I am creating a slightly modified version which starts from front. excited! Thanks for the wonderful function!

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm:

```
def solve(subList: List[Int], ammount: Int) = ammount match {
  case 0 => true
  case _ => sublist match {
    case Nil => false 
    case x::xs => {
      val rest = ammount - x
      solve(xs, ammount) || rest >= 0 && solve(xs, rest)
    }
  }
}


solve(list, ammount)
```

Explanation:

You can get `ammount` in `list`:

1. if you take first element and can get `ammount - first element` within `list without first element`
2. if you doesn't take first element and you can get `ammount` within `list without first element`

So we have reduction on each step of recursion.

We terminate with `true` when ammount is collected and with `false` when sublist is empty with non-zero ammount.

Example:
from (50,50,20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30) need 100:
`solve((50,50,20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30), 100)`

We can if

```
solve((50,20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30), 100) == true || solve((50,20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30), 50) == true
```

next step:
from (50,20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30) need 50

`solve((50,20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30), 50)`

We can if

```
solve((20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30), 0) == true || solve((20,10,20,150,150,50,70,30), 50) == true
```

first one is `true` => terminate

Comment: Hint: Explain an algorithm in any case. It's not about the poster to copy and paste but to understand.

Comment: In which language it is?

Comment: It is Scala. All you need is correct algorithm. You can implement it in Java.

Comment: Thanks Sergey! It took me some time to understand your function. I didn't understood at first because I am not familier with scala. But yes this also works great. Now, I understood. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I believe best way to find out which indices have to be picked to reach your sum is having the amounts sorted in an array. (e.g. build them up sorted if this is possible)

then you can iterate until you hit the sum and abort if you are over it.

However, a bit more of context would be helpful, since this task does not seem very useful ..

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing it in one of my function. But it feels a little bit complex. The sorted array is must for solving this.

Comment: That won't cover all the possibilities.

Comment: Yeah, I believe in this case it is really more related to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Find all the possible subsets and check If any of the subset sum 
will match with the target amount.
```

Update

```
Its better to calculate the sum immediately and checking after finding each subset. So that 
we could skip atleast few subsets finding them.
```

Comment: `2^n`, not that bad at all

Comment: That is very bad. Imagine you've got a list of 100 elements. Guess how many subsets you can get from there

Comment: It's 2^n, as Mateus said, guess How much is 2^100

Comment: That was the problem when I worked with the map of string and float. Performance