# Return Path at the root node when using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function for [subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem). I have created a function inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39121429/1820644).

Problem: I am trying to pick some elements from array some array (e.g. [50,40,30,20])  whose sum is given my some value defined as `sum` (e.g. 100).

I have created slightly modified function as suggested in that answer.

Picking up from the front and selected it or not selecting it.

If I select an element, the sum from the reduced list will be less than the element selected, else if I do not select that element, the sum from the reduced list will be the original one.

But, what I am finding the most difficult thing is returning the path traced to the root node of the recursive calls. I am able to print the path when I reached the node where sum is matched.

Here is my function:

```
private static boolean findSumFromSubList(ArrayList<Integer> set, Integer sum, ArrayList<Integer> result) {

    if (sum < 0)
        return false;

    if (sum == 0) {
        // Got it! Awesome! Print it!
        System.out.println(result);
        return true;
    }

    if (set.size() == 0 && sum != 0)
        return false;

    ArrayList<Integer> newSet = new ArrayList<>(set);
    newSet.remove(0);

    System.out.println("Left: Picking up " + set.get(0));
    result.add(set.get(0));
    if (findSumFromSubList(newSet, sum - set.get(0), new ArrayList<>(result))) {
        return true;
    }

    System.out.println("Right: NOT Picking up " + set.get(0));
    result.remove(result.size()-1);
    if (findSumFromSubList(newSet, sum, new ArrayList<>(result))) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I am calling it this way:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> pair = new ArrayList<>();
    pair.add(50);
    pair.add(40);
    pair.add(30);
    pair.add(20);
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean resultBool = findSumFromSubList(pair, 100, result);

    System.out.println("bool: " + resultBool + ", result: " + result);
```

The output I am getting is:

```
Left: Picking up 50
Left: Picking up 40
Left: Picking up 30
Right: NOT Picking up 30
Left: Picking up 20
Right: NOT Picking up 20
Right: NOT Picking up 40
Left: Picking up 30
Left: Picking up 20
[50, 30, 20]
bool: true, result: [50]
```

So I am able to get the output inside the recursion, but how can I return that value to the root calling function. Because `result` returns 50 only.

Comment: Hint: bad naming - "getSum()" sound like: it gets a sum. Better call it hasSublistThatHasGivenSum" or sumthing like that.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, I was just playing with it to get it working.Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of copying `result`, try passing it along so it can be modified as it recurses.

```
private static boolean getSum(ArrayList<Integer> set, Integer sum, LinkedList<Integer> result) {
    // ...

    System.out.println("Left: Picking up " + set.get(0));
    result.add(set.get(0));
    if (getSum(newSet, sum - set.get(0), result)) {
        return true;
    }
    result.removeLast();

    System.out.println("Right: NOT Picking up " + set.get(0));
    if (getSum(newSet, sum, result)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can apply similar logic to `set`, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Hey! It worked! Excellent. It was confusing where to change that result array. Can you explain that two lines where you use `result.add` and `result.remove` ?

Comment: It's like a stack. We push our current attempt on top, and pop it off when it fails.

Comment: Didn't I doing the same thing in arraylist with `result.add(set.get(0))` and `result.remove(result.size()-1)` ?

Comment: If you did, it's not in your post.

Comment: But, with this I was getting 50 at the end. Everything else popped out until it reached the end

Comment: Your edit doesn't work at all. You're popping without adding.

Comment: Check now. I've edited twice in succession. I found the buzzing bug! It was `new ArrayList<>(result)` while calling in the right node. So it looses reference to the original object when called. Java pass-by-value with same reference changed there! Ohh!!